# LinearLayouts in ViewFlipper as a different activity

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewflipper

I am using a ViewFlipper to navigate between different views(from LinearLayouts). Each Views is a kind of Form and in each view i want to validate my data forms. I have not been able to achieve validations properly within the viewflipper.

My xml file is as:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="#6B8AAD"
        android:layout_margin="3dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.80">
        <ViewFlipper 
            android:id="@+id/flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <include layout="@layout/view1" android:id="@+id/view1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <include layout="@layout/view2" android:id="@+id/view2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <include layout="@layout/view3" android:id="@+id/view3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <include layout="@layout/view4" android:id="@+id/view4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>
```

---------------------view1 xml and the rest are some kind of same.------------------------

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#6B8AAD"
android:weightSum="0.70">
<TextView 
    android:text="Citizenship Certificate No."
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtCitizenshipCertificateNo" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<TextView 
    android:text="District" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDistrict" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView 
    android:text="Date of Issue of Identity Card"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtDateOfIssueOfIdentityCardForNonDisabled"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<TextView 
    android:text="Father's Name" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtFatherName" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<TextView 
    android:text="Mother's Name" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtMotherName" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

---

My Problem is on validating this form data.
I have a menu at my last view which is to preview the input data.
If this form or other form of any views are not filled i wish to show that view/form to user.
If i could use each view as an activity then i could have done the validation. But I have single activity where my lines of code has already been aroubnd 2000. I wish to accomplish with modularity in my code.
Please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: None seems to answer me. is my question not a valid one?

Comment: I do not want to put all my codes inside one activity but rather, to have different activities for each view. Is that possible to implement? Or am i wrong in implementing it. If i am wrong how would i achieve as i required.